# EIGRP neighbors discovering process

Tags: eigrp

Quick question regarding EIGRP, as far I know, EIGRP has two tables: neighbors, and topology, and the router has its routing table obtained with DUAL algorithm applied to the topology table.

Regarding the EIGRP neighbor discovering process, does EIGRP exchange the ROUTER routing table or the EIGRP topology table inside the UPDATE packets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good question, as there is a lot of inaccurate information about this.

EIGRP neighbors exchange data from the EIGRP topology table.

The routing table contains routes learned from different sources -- EIGRP, other routing protocols such as OSPF and BGP, static, and connected routes.   To include these other information sources, you need to redistribute the other source into EIGRP.

Comment: Hello Ron, "as there is a lot of inaccurate information about this." Exactly ! This is why I asked this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, Topology Table as Ron stated.

I will base my answer on this document [EIGRP startup process - Unicast and multicast Updates containing topology information](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/wan-routing-and-switching/eigrp-startup-process-unicast-and-multicast-updates-containing/td-p/2782761)